# Does Power Query hold all tables in a query in memory when not in the editor?

Tags: excel, powerbi, powerquery, data-cleaning, m

I have some Excel files that use power query to get data through an internal ODBC connection. I need to distribute the files to other computers in the business. Data security isn't a concern because all of the computers operate on the internal network only. The computers in question are quite old and there's not much chance of replacements coming soon.
I've got 2 options in terms of constructing the queries: either do it in VBA with data manipulation happening there (I'd rather avoid this option), or do it all in PQ which I'm more familiar with.
What I'm not sure about is if these options have the same load on memory or if one will reduce it substantially. Processing capacity is also a concern, but not as big a problem as memory.
I know VBA will load everything into memory when it executes and then dump it all once the sub routine finishes. Does PQ hold all the query tables in memory all the time, or does it only load them while the query executes and while it's being edited?

I've had files built both ways, but haven't had the time to build the same functionality twice to test properly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default, Power Query streams data rather than load it all into memory at once. There is an excellent video here which discusses the inner workings:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AIvneMAE50o

Comment: That is a great resource, just to add some extra information here, some transformation are non-streaming by nature such as Sorts, Aggregations and Merges. It is important to understand that each query is run independently, they don't share the same process, even if they share the same reference in PQ.

Comment: @davidebacci Thanks very much, that resource explained a lot that I was missing before. So PQ would be much more efficient than VBA because, barring the non-streamable steps, it'll deal with things 1 at a time and only keep the data necessary for the final output.

Comment: @davidebacci take a look a this series of posts from Chris Webb.
https://blog.crossjoin.co.uk/2020/06/07/optimising-the-performance-of-power-query-merges-in-power-bi-part-3-table-join-and-sortmerge/
This one is related to Merges, and how you can (in a very specific case) turn a Blocking operation like Merge to a semi-Blocking with SortMerge, data arrives sorted, the data can advance once that Key is done. But the principle is the same with Aggregates, you can only move foward after you scan all the data and seen all the rows to identify the keys.

Comment: Thanks - I'll have a read